# Is there a way to detect the "humanness" of users from the facebook api?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

A site I'm working for is having significant problems with fake users through facebook openID. Is there an API call which reports on the internal facebook calculations of the "humanness" of a user and/or indications that the account has been compromised?

Answer (score 1):

If there were internal Facebook calculations of the "humanness" of a user, then there wouldn't fake users using openId to your client's website.  Facebook would have already removed them.

You can check the verified field of the user Graph API object.

> A user is considered verified if she takes any of the following
>   actions:
>
> - Registers for mobile
> - Confirms her account via SMS
> - Enters a valid credit card

You may want to play politics like some sites have done saying, you need X nbr of friends, have a profile pic, etc.